# Problems retrieving the correct values from DB from REST Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, url, web

I Have the following XML if I do a get to List the content of the table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
   <competitions> 
       <competition>
           <competitionPK> 
               <competitionName>Test Thing</competitionName> 
               <edition>First Thing</edition> 
           </competitionPK> 
           <description>Test Thing ONE</description>
       </competition> 
       <competition> 
           <competitionPK> 
               <competitionName>Test Thing 2</competitionName> 
               <edition>Second Thing</edition> 
           </competitionPK> 
           <description>Test Thing TWO</description> 
       </competition> 
   </competitions>
```

This is URL that exposes the service:

```
http://localhost:8080/project/org.project.rest.application.config.competition/%7Bid%7D
```

How can I obtain the data of only the second competition = Test Thing 2?

I've tried with...

```
http://localhost:8080/project/org.project.rest.application.config.competition/%STest%20Thing%2%B4Second%20Thing%7D
```

... which seems logical but it gives 204 error as no content was found.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Are we supposed to just guess what framework you're using?

Comment: These rest services were automatically generated using Netbeans functionality of creating REST Web Services from the database.

Comment: Well show it... Test if the expected method is being hit. And second make sure the expected object is not null. If it is, you will get a 204 no content. This is assuming you're using JAX-RS (which Netbeans has auto-generation support for)